# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter?

Tags: c#

Hi im extremely new to coding and following a udemy unity tutorial that is also educating me in c# this is my error Assets\WM2000\Scripts\Hacker.cs(34,9): error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'input' of 'Hacker.OnUserInput(string)'
and this is my code

I have a Pastebin of a small portion of my code that i want to correct here https://pastebin.com/QhW1cn3Dk` void OnUserInput(string input)

```
if (input == "menu")
    {
        ShowMainMenu();
    }
    else if (CurrentScreen == screen.MainMenu)
    {
        RunMainMenu(input);
    }
    else if (CurrentScreen == screen.Password)
    {
        CheckPassword(input);
    }
    CurrentScreen = screen.UserName;
    Terminal.WriteLine("Please Enter your Username:");
    if (input == Username)
    {
        ClearScreen();
        CurrentScreen = screen.Login;
        Terminal.WriteLine("Please Enter your password");
    }
    if (input == bpassword)
    {
        ShowMainMenu();
    }
```

Comment: The link you posted in your post doesnt work ... please update your question as well

Answer (score 1):

The error isn't inside your function it is wherever you are calling your function. By declaring your function as `OnUserInput(string input)`, anytime you call the function you must provide it with a string. The error is stating that at `Hacker.cs(34,9)` (Hacker.cs > line 34 > character 9) you are calling `OnUserInput()` without passing it a string parameter. If you are passing in a variable then make sure that it is a string.